# How do I update the project id in the .boto file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, boto, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

gsutil has set the project id in .boto for an old project. I tried creating a new bucket in my new project with `gsutil mb gs://new-project-id` but got the error message:

`In the project overview, ensure that the Project Number listed for your project matches the project ID (old-project-id) from your boto config file`

It looks like I cant change it from directly opening the file because all the values look like variables stored somewhere else and I cant find anything that looks like a project id.

How do I change the project id for the .boto file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the gcloud distribution of gsutil you can set the default project id using the gcloud config set command, e.g.,

```
gcloud config set project my-other-project
```

If you're using the standalone distribution of gsutil you can change the default project id by editing the default_project_id setting in your .boto file.

Note also that you can override the default project ID for particular gsutil ls and gsutil mb commands, using the -p option, e.g.,

```
gsutil mb -p my-other-project gs://some-bucket
```